# How do I convert column having memory size Ex. MB & KB and I want all of the values in MB?

Tags: r, string

I'm having a column with memory sizes like in Mb and kb. I want to convert all the values to Mb in R.

`$ Size          : Factor w/ 462 levels "","1.0M","1.1M","0.98k"..`

Comment: Please show enough sample data to cover all memory types.  For example, does GB also appear?

Comment: There is no GB, this is all kind of values I have in columns:- `SampleData <- c(“19M”, “14M”,  “24M”, “Varies with device “, ”1.1M”, ”9.4M”, ”Varies with device “, ”201k”, ” 360k”)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you only have kilobytes and megabytes.  Here is a working base R solution:

```
input <- c("Varies with device", "9.4M", "201k", "0.98k")
output <- sapply(input, function(x) {
    ifelse(grepl("k$", x), paste0(0.001*as.numeric(sub("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)k", "\\1", x)), "M"), x)
})
output

[1] "Varies with device", "9.4M", "0.201M", "0.00098M"
```

This solution uses `grepl` to find all matching kilobyte entries.  For such entries, it extracts the numerical component, casts to numeric, and then scales down by a thousand to convert to megabytes.

Comment: ```input <- db$Size
output <- sapply(input, function(x) {
    ifelse(grepl("k$", x), paste0(0.001*as.numeric(sub("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)k", "\\1", x)), "M"), x)
})
output
``` [1] "55"     "29"     "368"    "101"    "64"     "222"    "55"     "117"    "145"    "120"    "113"    "24"     "72"     "76"     "160"    "63"     "221"    "45"     "164"   
  [20] "138"    "29"     "24"     "168"    "310"    "88"     "265"    "101"    "266"    "172"    "168"    "319"    "101"    "255"    "256"    "462"    "152"    "145"    "145"    "222"   
  [58] "245"    "0.201M" "125"

Comment: It's giving right output for a sample or small data but not for my data.

Comment: I don't know the exact structure of your data.  Perhaps you need to use `lapply`.

Comment: `> str(db$Size)`
 Factor w/ 462 levels "","1.0M","1.1M",..: 55 29 368 101 64 222 55 117 145 120 ...`> typeof(db$Size)`
[1] "integer"

Answer (score 0):

A little clunky, but this works.  Should also work if GB or G appears later on:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

SampleData <- c("19M", "14M", "24M", "Varies with device", "1.1M", "9.4M", "Varies with device", "201k", "360k")

data <- tibble(strings = SampleData)

data %>%
 mutate(number = as.double(str_extract(strings, ".+(?=[:alpha:])")), #extract the numeric portion and make it a double variable
        letters = str_extract(strings, "[:alpha:]+"),
        number = if_else(letters == "k", number/1000, number),
        combined = paste0(number, "M"),
        strings = if_else(is.na(number), strings, combined)) %>%
 select(strings)


# A tibble: 9 x 1
  strings           
  <chr>             
1 19M               
2 14M               
3 24M               
4 Varies with device
5 1.1M              
6 9.4M              
7 Varies with device
8 0.201k            
9 0.36k
```

Comment: NAs introduced by coercionError: `false` must be a `factor` object, not a character vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace  Your code is giving this error.

Comment: `> str(db$Size)`
 Factor w/ 462 levels "","1.0M","1.1M",..: 55 29 368 101 64 222 55 117 145 120 ...  `> typeof(db$Size)`
[1] "integer"